# Can CANBUS wires be used in same cable as 12V

Tags: can

I mean a multiwire cable - with four separate wires put into single isolated cable [like this](https://www.cmple.com/phone-cable-flat-4-wire-solid-silver-1000ft-28awg/). Two would be for CAN, one for 12V and another for -12V (GND). Would it cause interference? Or would it be suitable for lower speed CAN?

Comment: CAN needs a specific line impedanze of 120Ohms - a long as you use suche a cable, you can also transmitt power over unused pairs.

Comment: The answer depends upon application.  One of or a million units.  CAN requires twisted pair.  Power can be sent over the same cable.  Not twited pair probably limits speed AND/OR distance.

Comment: Depends on cable lengths, baudrate, current consumption/voltage drop, type of cable, type of application etc etc. It is _common_ to use CAN data + supply in the same cable. Will it cause interference in your specific case? We can't tell with the info given.

Comment: Ethernet is a cheap and easily available cable you can use for CAN. [CAN in Automation](https://www.can-cia.org/groups/specifications/) specifies in *CiA 106 v1.0.0* the RJ45 connector as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOWuo.png

Comment: There's also super expensive 5 pin M12 PUR cables that keep ground + supply in thicker wires than the CAN lines, and shield each individual line. Completely overkill for most use-cases.

Comment: Describe your project a bit more detailed, please. Else you can't get much more than "it depends" and "probably yes/no".

Comment: It is for a vehicle, so up to 10m and ~5-7 devices.

Comment: @RiDi Still that doesn't say much. What is the 12V powering? I take it it's the raw voltage from the alternator/battery and not regulated? In this something with a starter engine hooked to that 12V? Or other heavy consumers like motors or valves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as always, depends.

Typically CAN bus cabling uses twisted pairs to provide common-mode noise immunity. You can purchase 4 conductor cabling specifically for CAN which will provide a TP and power and ground wires.

Not using twisted pair significantly reduces the reliability of your implementation.

At low data rates, line termination and twisted vs. untwisted are less critical (though still important!), but at higher data rates (approaching and beyond 1 Mbps) you will need proper termination, controlled stub length, and twisted pair is mandatory.

CAN is pretty robust and you can definitely get away with more than the spec would imply, though at degraded performance.

In summary: Control the stub length, keep the bus length to a minimum, use twisted pair for data, terminate the bus properly (120 Ω differential), and reduce data rate if your application requirements can tolerate it.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it cause interference?

Depends on the application, but possibly. Because, ...

> Or would it be suitable for lower speed CAN?

... CAN bus wires generally need to be twisted pairs (TP) regardless of the speed and distance (ISO 11898-1:2015 suggests TP or parallel). Shielding is not a necessity. Twisted pairs (TP) are more noise-proof than parallel cables, so better to use TPs.